# Creating a list of unique street names from a list of address

Tags: address, streets

I would like to generate a unique list of street names from a list of UK addresses, but obviously there will be a number of streets with the same name.  I want to distinguish between streets that are genuinely different.

On AtoZ, the street names on the index is written as:

```
Bell street, RH1
High Street, RH1
```

and so on.  I have yet to come across a street name with more than one outcode.  So based on this,

```
34, Bell street, RH1 6HH and 
36, Bell street, RH1 6HJ
```

would refer to the same street, but say you had

```
34, Bell street, RH1 6HH and
36, Bell street, RH2 6HJ
```

can I be certain that these are two different streets?

Answer (score 1):

There is only that much that can be done with 'poor' source data.

- Scenario 1 - Limited information:
  If the source address information is missing full the postcode (i.e. RH1 instead of RH1 6HH)
  and there is not additional information like street number, or spatial location (i.e. LAT/LON, point geometry). I'm afraid the answer is **NO, you cannot be 100% certain** that 2 streets with same name and from same UK district (i.e. SW16) are genuine streets or duplicates in the registry.

Comment: I'm not sure this is poor data.  You have the full postcode.  I guess my question is, is the outcode part of the postcode is designed so that it won't contain different streets with the same name?